# Suppress headers when page contains a section title using titlesec

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I'm writing a `book` with [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and try to suppress headers containing the section name, when the section starts at the top of the respective page. Given that all my sections start on a new page I tried `\assignpagestyle`, but it doesn't work. Manually adding `\thispagestyle` for each section works, but there should be a better solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\renewpagestyle{headings}{%
  \sethead[\chaptertitle][][]
      {}{}{\thesection~\sectiontitle}%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}%
}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}%
}
\pagestyle{headings}
\newpagestyle{section}{%
  \sethead[\chaptertitle][][]
      {}{}{}%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}%
}
\assignpagestyle{\section}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{header ok}
\clearpage

\section{First}     % warning here
even page
\clearpage

\section{Second}    % warning here
suppress header here, odd page, start section on top
\clearpage
chapter headers are ok, even page
\clearpage
keep header here, odd page, no new section

\end{document}
```

Using MikTeX 2.8 I get the following warnings:

```
Package titlesec Warning: Page style in straigh class ignored on input line <XXX>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\section}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}
```

Or should you want to suppress headers only for *odd* pages containing section titles:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\xpretocmd{\section}{\ifthispageodd{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}}{}{}
```

Comment: Using `\usepackage{xpatch}` and 
`\xpretocmd{\section}{\thispagestyle{section}}{}{}` is equivalent to your second solution, where the odd/even distinction is made using `titletoc` in the definition of `\newpagestyle{section}`.

Answer (score 4):

The warning

```
Package titlesec Warning: Page style in straight class ignored on input line 30
```

gives you a hint about the problem: the page style you defined for section pages wasn't applied and the reason is that `\section` is, by default, (using the `titlesec` terminology) of `straight` class; i.e., is intended to produce titles in the middle of text. To allow the application of the page style, you can change the class of `\section` to `top`:

```
\titleclass{\section}{top}
```

This, together with `\newcommand\sectionbreak{\clearpage}`
will give the desired result (the spacing for section titles is corrected using `\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*-3}{*1.5}`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\titleclass\section{top}
\newcommand\sectionbreak{\clearpage}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*-3}{*1.5}

\renewpagestyle{headings}{%
  \sethead[\chaptertitle][][]
      {}{}{\thesection~\sectiontitle}%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}%
}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}%
}
\pagestyle{headings}
\newpagestyle{section}{%
  \sethead[\chaptertitle][][]
      {}{}{}%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}%
}
\assignpagestyle{\section}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{header ok}
\clearpage

\section{First}     % warning here
even page
\clearpage

\section{Second}    % warning here
suppress header here, odd page, start section on top
\clearpage
chapter headers are ok, even page
\clearpage
keep header here, odd page, no new section

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will add two pages in the OP's example, as `\section`s now start on odd pages.

Comment: @lockstep: not necessarily; if the OP uses `\sectionbreak` to start a new page with `\section`, then there will be no additional pages.

Comment: That's better, but the space above `\section` is still different from the OP's version.

Comment: @lockstep: true. I've added a comment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: `\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*-3}{*1.5}` corrects the space above `\section`, proposed edit of your answer.