# Hiding headline when page contains \section

Tags: header-footer, xpatch

I use the `{scrlayer-scrpage}` package for headlines and footlines and want to hide the headline and headsepline when my page contains `\section`.

I found a similar question here: [Suppress headers when page contains a section title using titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52756/suppress-headers-when-page-contains-a-section-title-using-titlesec) but I have the problem that I am not able to activate the header afterwards.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside=false, DIV=12, BCOR=5mm, bibliography=totocnumbered, numbers=autoendperiod]{scrartcl}

% Set up headers and footers
\usepackage[automark, autooneside=false, headsepline, footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\headheight=1cm
\footheight=1cm
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\leftmark}}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\ofoot{\pagemark} 

% Page Style for page which shall contain the page number only
\newpairofpagestyles{pagenumbersonly}{
    \KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}
    \ofoot{\pagemark}
}

% Fixing pagestyle for pages containing \section command
\xpretocmd{\section}{\thispagestyle{pagenumbersonly}\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true}}{}{}
```

I handle the content of the headline by using `\ihead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\leftmark}}`, that works fine for all styles. Otherwise I would have a headline printing the section twice. But how do I get the the headsepline activated for the following pages? I tried to add `\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true}` after applying the pagestyle in `xpretocmd`, but the headsepline will not be displayed.

An example for that:

```
\section{sec}
\subsection{subsec}
\lipsum{}\lipsum{}
```

produces the result:

**EDIT: As requested, the full example:**

```
%% Based on a TeXnicCenter-Template by Tino Weinkauf.

\documentclass[a4paper, twoside=false, DIV=12, BCOR=5mm, bibliography=totocnumbered, numbers=autoendperiod]{scrartcl}

% Options:
% Paper Size: a4paper / a5paper / b5paper / letterpaper / legalpaper / executivepaper
% Duplex: oneside / twoside
% Base Font Size: 10pt / 11pt / 12pt
% DIV 12 normed content- and margin size
% BCOR Bindekorrektur - 5mm more space on the left


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                             % German language support
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                             % UTF-8 encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                    % Westeuropean encoding support
\usepackage{lmodern}                                            % Font-fix
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}      % Fix for chapter font
\usepackage{microtype}                                      % Better letters
\usepackage{graphicx}                                           % For loading graphic files
\usepackage{siunitx}                                            % For units

% Please note:
% Images can be included using \includegraphics{Dateiname}
% resp. using the dialog in the Insert menu.
% 
% The mode "LaTeX => PDF" allows the following formats:
%   .jpg  .png  .pdf  .mps
% 
% The modes "LaTeX => DVI", "LaTeX => PS" und "LaTeX => PS => PDF"
% allow the following formats:
%   .eps  .ps  .bmp  .pict  .pntg

\usepackage{listings, lstautogobble}            % For formatting Code, for formatting Indents
\usepackage{lscape}                                             % Single page landscape layout support
\usepackage{pdflscape}                                      % Single page landscape layout support for PDF files
\usepackage{pdfpages}                                           % Embedding PDF documents in the final document


% Set up headers and footers
\usepackage[automark, autooneside=false, headsepline, footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\headheight=1cm
\footheight=1cm
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\leftmark}}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\ofoot{\pagemark} 

% Page Style for page which shall contain the page number only
\newpairofpagestyles{pagenumbersonly}{
    \KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}
    \ofoot{\pagemark}
}

% Fixing pagestyle for pages containing \section command
\xpretocmd{\section}{\thispagestyle{pagenumbersonly}\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true}}{}{}

% Automark fills the \leftmark and \rightmark placeholders with the section and subsection
% Autooneside is needed by automark
% Headsepline adds a line under the headline
% Footsepline adds a line over the footline
% Headheight defines an additional spacing over the headline

\usepackage{tikz-er2}                                           % TIKZ for figures
\usetikzlibrary{shadows, positioning}                           % TIKZ libraries

\usepackage{lipsum}                                             % For testing purposes. Remove if finished

% Math Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% Line Spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing        %% 1-spacing (default)
%\onehalfspacing       %% 1,5-spacing
%\doublespacing        %% 2-spacing

% Other Packages

%\usepackage{soul}
%\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}


% Babelbib for German citation style
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{ngerman}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin} % Using modified alphadin compiler


% Abb. instead of Abbildung as Caption
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}}

% Bracket on the right

%\newenvironment{rcases}
%  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
%  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={hidden},
    pdfauthor={hidden},
    pdfkeywords={hiddén},
    bookmarksopen=true
}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\section{
    ~\vspace{1cm}
    \@startsection 
   {section}{1}{0mm}%         % name, ebene, einzug 
   {\baselineskip}%            % vor-abstand 
   {2\baselineskip}%            % nach-abstand 
   {\bfseries\sffamily\LARGE}%      % layout 
   } 
\makeatother 

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection 
   {subsection}{2}{0mm}%      % name, ebene, einzug 
   {2\baselineskip}%            % vor-abstand 
   {1.33\baselineskip}%            % nach-abstand 
   {\bfseries\sffamily\large}%           % layout 
   } 
\makeatother 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DOCUMENT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    %% Title Page %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


    %% TOC %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \pagestyle{pagenumbersonly}

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

    \newpage


    %% Main Content %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \pagestyle{scrheadings} % Now display headings: headings / fancy / ...

    %Hauptinhalt

    \section{sec}
    \subsection{subsec}
    \lipsum{}\lipsum{}\lipsum{}\lipsum{}

    %\input{Content}
    %\newpage
    %\includepdf[scale=0.7, pagecommand=\thispagestyle{scrheadings}\section{Entity-Relationship Diagramm}]{resources/images/ER.pdf}

    \newpage

    %% Literature %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \pagestyle{scrheadings}

    \interlinepenalty 10000             % Avoid a pagebreak in a source
    %\bibliography{literature}

    \newpage


    %% Disclaimer %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %\appendix

\end{document}
```

[image: page containing \section]

[image: page after the page containing \section]

The headlinecontent is correct at both pages. But how do I enable the headsepline for the following pages again (which do not contain `\section`)?

**EDIT 2:** I found out it works perfectly as expected when I remove the lines

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\section{
    ~\vspace{1cm}
    \@startsection 
     {section}{1}{0mm}%         % name, ebene, einzug 
     {\baselineskip}%            % vor-abstand 
     {2\baselineskip}%            % nach-abstand 
     {\bfseries\sffamily\LARGE}%      % layout 
     } 
\makeatother 

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection 
     {subsection}{2}{0mm}%      % name, ebene, einzug 
     {2\baselineskip}%            % vor-abstand 
     {1.33\baselineskip}%            % nach-abstand 
     {\bfseries\sffamily\large}%           % layout 
     } 
\makeatother
```

Can someone explain me why this works now and what I can do instead of deleting those lines?

Comment: Please provide an example we can copy-paste-compile rather than just fragments. It makes it much easier to help as we don't have to play a guessing game concerning the bits we need to add to reproduce the problem. Setting head and foot height like that manually is not a good idea if you are using `typearea` to layout your page (which you are), since `typearea` will not take account of changes you don't let it know about.

Comment: Why do you set the headsepline for the number-only pages to `true`? Don't you want it to be `false`? If not, there isn't much point in setting the page style up with `false` in the first place.

Comment: @cfr thanks for your hint, I added my full example and reduced the content to a minimum. The error still appears there. I tried to apply the headsepline-style to the number-only pages with: `\newpairofpagestyles{pagenumbersonly}\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false} [...] }` and set the `headsepline` to true _afterwards_ in xpretocmd for the following pages. But this didn't work.

Comment: And can you tell me where I use `typearea` exactly? I cannot find it in my document. Or is it a part of a package?

Comment: @cfr I might found a solution and edited a post. Can you give me a hint what I can do instad of deleting those lines?

Comment: The KOMA classes all use `typearea`. `typearea` deals with the `a4paper, twoside=false, DIV=12, BCOR=5mm`. It calculates everything using that information. Then you go and sneakily change the page layout behind its back trying to make it look foolish ;).

Comment: See page 42 of KOMA's manual for setting the area for the footer and header appropriately. (Number is for the English language version.) By the way, that line cannot possibly be fixing the chapter font because you are using a class without chapters.

Comment: Don't be offended, but your preamble is a bit of a mess. See the KOMA documentation if you really must use `setspace`. Don't load packages twice - especially not with different options. `hyperref` needs to be loaded late. You don't need `lscape` as well as `pdflscape`. Overwriting KOMA's sectioning commands will produce a less good result than working with KOMA - it goes to a lot of trouble to make your document look nice. (If you don't think it looks nice, start with a standard class instead.)

Comment: No, I'm not offended. It's just the first time I have to write a big document with LaTeX, in this case my Bachelor Thesis. There are some formal things I have to keep in mind. A 1.5 line spacing was one of those examples. It's really hard to get an insight which packages exist and can do what. Currently I'm lucky when it works :) But I'll try to clean up my document a bit when I have the hints. Thanks!

Comment: See page 448 of the KOMA manual for what you should do if you need `setspace` to alter the line spacing. You need to have `typearea` recalculate things after changing the spacing. Thesis format requirements are a pain. They seem designed to produce theses which are readable but inevitably ugly ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not redefine `\section` and `\subsection`. You can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change `beforeskip` and `afterskip`

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=2\baselineskip,
  font=\sffamily\LARGE
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1.33\baselineskip,
  font=\sffamily\large
]{subsection}
```

This code have to be inserted before prepending code to `\section`.

To remove the `headsepline` only on pages with `pagenumbersonly` style you can use

```
\newpairofpagestyles{pagenumbersonly}{\ofoot{\pagemark}}
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{pagenumbersonly}{oninit=\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[DIV=12, BCOR=5mm, bibliography=totocnumbered,
headheight=1cm,
footheight=1cm
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}% why??
\usepackage{microtype}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=2\baselineskip,
  font=\sffamily\LARGE
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1.33\baselineskip,
  font=\sffamily\large
]{subsection}

% Set up headers and footers
\usepackage[automark, autooneside=false, headsepline, footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\ofoot{\pagemark}

% Page Style for page which shall contain the page number only
\newpairofpagestyles{pagenumbersonly}{\ofoot{\pagemark}}
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{pagenumbersonly}{oninit=\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}}

% Fixing pagestyle for pages containing \section command
\xpretocmd{\section}{\vspace*{1cm}\thispagestyle{pagenumbersonly}}{}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}                                             % For testing 

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{pagenumbersonly}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\clearpage
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\section{sec}
\subsection{subsec}
\lipsum[1-6]
\lipsum[1-7]
%\lipsum[1-5]% uncomment to see the problem
\section{sec}
\subsection{subsec}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

I have removed the stuff that is not needed for the question and I have used

```
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
```

to ensure that only `\leftmark` is printed if `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` are equal.

---

Another suggestion is using page style `plain` instead defining the new one.

```
\documentclass[DIV=12, BCOR=5mm, bibliography=totocnumbered,
headheight=1cm,
footheight=1cm
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}% why??
\usepackage{microtype}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=2\baselineskip,
  font=\sffamily\LARGE
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1.33\baselineskip,
  font=\sffamily\large
]{subsection}

% Set up headers and footers
\usepackage[automark, autooneside=false, headsepline, footsepline,
plainfootsepline
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}


% Fixing pagestyle for pages containing \section command
\xpretocmd{\section}{\vspace*{1cm}\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\clearpage
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\section{sec}
\subsection{subsec}
\lipsum[1-6]
\lipsum[1-7]
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{sec}
\subsection{subsec}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

---

Note that there will be a problem if an automatical page break is done when the section starts. Then the `pagenumbersonly` style is set on the page before. Uncomment the `\lipsum[1-5]` command to see this problem.

---

**Update**

Maybe you want to use the `scrreprt` class and `\chapter`s:

```
\documentclass[DIV=12, BCOR=5mm, bibliography=totocnumbered,
headheight=1cm,
footheight=1cm
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}% why??
\usepackage{microtype}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=\dimexpr-1cm-1\baselineskip\relax,
  afterskip=2\baselineskip,
  font=\sffamily\LARGE
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1.33\baselineskip,
  font=\sffamily\large
]{section}

% Set up headers and footers
\usepackage[automark, autooneside=false, headsepline, footsepline,
plainfootsepline
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}                                             % For testing 

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\clearpage\relax
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup

\clearpage
\chapter{sec}
\section{subsec}
\lipsum[1-6]
\lipsum[1-6]
%\lipsum[1-5]% uncomment to see the problem
\chapter{sec}
\section{subsec}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is a lot of cleaner than mine. It was intended not even having a `\leftmark` when there is a `\section` on the page, so I removed this. Unfortunately your `beforeskip` in the `RedeclareSectionCommand` does not work every time. I think the beforeskip is relative to preceding text. That causes a space when there was text before but when there is a `\newpage\section`, the beforeskip does not work. There is no additionally skip of 1cm relative to the headline as I archived it with my `vspace{1cm}` before. It should look like the image in my question. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: See my edited answer. You prepend `\vspace*{1cm}` to the `\section` command and use `beforeskip=-1\baselineskip`. But maybe you want to use class like `scrreprt` that uses `\chapter`s?

Comment: So I write `\vspace*{1cm}\section` everytime in my document when I create a new `\section`? I think I can life with that. The only question left is why does the `afterskip` option has a positive value while the `beforeskip` option has a negative value? Could you explain that, please?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I haven't seen the `vspace` in the `xpretocmd` in your edit. Now I'm satisfied :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my own problem. The problem is that the line:

```
\xpretocmd{\section}{\thispagestyle{pagenumbersonly} \KOMAoptions{headsepline=true}}{}{}
```

interferes with the lines

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\section{
    ~\vspace{1cm}
    \@startsection 
     {section}{1}{0mm}%         % name, ebene, einzug 
     {\baselineskip}%            % vor-abstand 
     {2\baselineskip}%            % nach-abstand 
     {\bfseries\sffamily\LARGE}%      % layout 
     } 
\makeatother 

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection 
     {subsection}{2}{0mm}%      % name, ebene, einzug 
     {2\baselineskip}%            % vor-abstand 
     {1.33\baselineskip}%            % nach-abstand 
     {\bfseries\sffamily\large}%           % layout 
     } 
\makeatother
```

I have to use `\xpretocmd` **after** the renewcommands. Then everything works as expected. I would be glad if someone could explain me this behaviour.

Comment: You see why a complete example is needed? Your original question did not mention the fact that you overwrote the commands after appending to them!

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I didn't thought that is relevant since the pagestyle was applied correctly to `\section` as it does not. But now the `\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true}` is interpreted, too, which I cannot explain to me.

Comment: That's the point of making a minimal working example. Then you figure out what *is* required. `\renewcommand` obliterates the existing definition of a command. So any changes you make to a command before that are obliterated.

Comment: The page style `pagenumbersonly` was not set by the `\section` command. With your code there was no entry in the header because of `\ihead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\leftmark}}\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}`. So if `\rightmark` is equal to `\leftmark` there will be an empty `\ihead` and an empty `\ohead`. Insert some text in the empty arguments then this text would be printed in the header of the page with your first section: `\ihead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{text}{\leftmark}}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{text}{\rightmark}}`.